# How can I pair Motorola CS3070 bluetooth barcode scanner with Nexus One?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I have a Motorola CS3070 bluetooth barcode scanner and a Nexus One. I followed [Use a Bluetooth Barcode Scanner with Android - Nexus S & Motorola Symbol CS3070 Scanner](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE3pE6ieNnI), but I can't pair the scanner with my Nexus One using bluetooth - they never get "paired".

How can I pair the bluetooth scanner with Nexus One? Doesn't it work with Nexus One?